# Why does a JPEG embedded into a PDF render slightly differently than the original?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript, mupdf, poppler

The PDF container allows one to embed a complete JPEG file (including header and all) into a document. But, even when the JPEG stored in a PDF is bit-by-bit identical to the original file, it will render slightly differently than the original JPEG does. I want to know why that is and how to make the JPEG in the PDF render precisely like the original JPEG file. Here is how to reproduce my findings:

## Setup

Take this test image (md5sum: `5085774e481966b3359df0745c57daca`)

[image: test image]

```
curl https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRHo8.jpg > test.jpg
```

And put it into a pdf container. You could use the tool [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf)

```
img2pdf --producer="" --nodate test.jpg > test.pdf
```

or you could use this gzipped base64 representation of the PDF:

```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```

Turn it into its original form by copypasting the base64 into a text file and running:

```
$ base64 -d test.txt | gzip -cd > test.pdf
```

md5sum of the final PDF: `156994ee6590ef8421fad1325378906d`

The probably crucial part:

```
6 0 obj
<</BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Filter /DCTDecode /Height
  60 /Length 1790 /Subtype /Image /Type /XObject /Width 60>>
stream
```

Looking at it in a PDF viewer will show you the original image. At least that's what you think, but there are tiny differences which we will reveal now. To test how the PDF is rendered we are using three different rendering engines, to make sure that this is a systematic error and probably not a problem with a particular rendering engine

### ghostscript

```
$ gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r96 -sOutputFile=gs.png test.pdf
```

### poppler

We use the `pdftocairo` tool from the `poppler-utils` package in Debian and derivatives.

```
$ pdftocairo -r 96 -png test.pdf poppler
```

### mupdf

```
$ mutool draw -o mupdf.png -r 96 test.pdf
```

## Evaluation

First observation: All three tools produce the same rendering of the PDF. We compare using imagemagick.

```
$ compare -metric AE mupdf.png gs.png null:
0
$ compare -metric AE poppler-1.png mupdf.png null:
0
$ compare -metric AE gs.png poppler-1.png null:
0
```

Now we compare to the original input image:

```
$ compare -metric AE mupdf.png test.jpg null:
105
$ compare -metric AE poppler-1.png test.jpg null:
105
$ compare -metric AE gs.png test.jpg null:
105
```

Lets visualize the differences:

[image: mupdf diff]
[image: poppler diff]
[image: gs diff]

One might think that some data was probably changed when we embedded `test.jpg` into the PDF container, so lets extract the JPEG from the PDF:

```
$ pdfimages -j test.pdf extracted
```

The data that `pdfimages` extracts from the PDF is exactly identical to the input image `test.jpg`:

```
$ cmp test.jpg extracted-000.jpg || echo different
$ md5sum extracted-000.jpg test.jpg
5085774e481966b3359df0745c57daca  extracted-000.jpg
5085774e481966b3359df0745c57daca  test.jpg
```

## Conclusion

So, evidently, the JPEG that is embedded in the PDF file is bit-by-bit the same as the original JPEG. Still, rendering the PDF produces a slightly different result than the input. Even more so: three different PDF engines produce the same difference.

Why is that?

How to make the PDF display exactly like the input JPEG?

Comment: Try decoding the original with `djpeg -dct int`, `djpeg -dct fast`, and `djpeg -dct float`

Comment: The jpeg decoding process has some freedom regarding some values to choose. Take for example the Google ["Knusperli"](https://github.com/google/knusperli) project which makes use of this and tries to decode jpeg files to a less "blocky" view.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Your comment pushed me in the right direction. Unfortunately, `djpeg` was not able to replicate the decoding of gs/poppler/mupdf exactly but `jpegtopnm` was able to do so. The `-dct int` option worked. Strangely, `djpeg` and `jpegtopnm` produce different results with this option...

Comment: @Robert Of course I knew that transforming a bitmap to JPEG is lossy but somehow naively I thought that once the encoding is done, there is only one way to correctly interpret that data. Thanks for teaching me something new! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that ImageMagick is using a different JPEG decoder to the other three engines, since they agree with each other. I know that Ghostscript and MuPDF use jpeglib, don't know about poppler.

So what you are saying isn't that the PDF varieties are 'wrong' just 'not the same as compare (the ImageMagick tool ?)' which isn't (IMO) the same thing. You can have Ghostscript render the original JPEG too, by using viewjpeg.ps in the lib directory, I'm fairly sure MuPDF can render a JPEG file directly as well. I'd bet that they render the JPEG the same as they do the PDF containing the JPEG.

JPEG is a lossy format, and the Discrete Cosine Transform which it uses is a mathematical transformation (it uses a high pass and low pass filter), I'd bet this is simply due to rounding differences in the maths used by the libraries when reconstituting the samples from the filtered data, I strongly suspect you cannot detect any differences by eye. Have you looked at the RGB values of the sample at the relevant locations in the images ?

I'd suggest you try using JPEG as direct input to MuPDF and Ghostscript (and poppler if it'll do it). My expectation is that the result will match the rendering of the PDF.

In which case, who is the odd mane out ?

Comment: The problem was indeed the decoder. Just by chance (I guess), ghostscript, poppler and mupdf choose the same way to decode the JPEG data. To replicate their way to decode the JPEG one can use: `jpegtopnm -dct int`. Strangely, `djpeg -dct int` will *not* produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Both are colorspace sRGB. But one difference is that your test.jpg has no color profile. But the test.pdf has an sRGB.icc profile, at least when converting with Imagemagick as `convert test.jpg test.pdf`. The addition of a color profile typically can change the viewing of the images even though the data is identical, but the viewing my be dependent upon the viewer and whether is assumes sRGB profile even it it is not there or ignores profile. Using Imagemagick identify -verbose, I see

test.jpg

```
 Properties:
    date:create: 2018-08-18T09:57:16-07:00
    date:modify: 2018-08-18T09:57:16-07:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: fa0b78710e2c79f1cc852e0ae805393ea96d1f51769beb9d1729ec330da71303
  Artifacts:
    filename: test.jpg
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 1790B
  Number pixels: 3600
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-10 Q16 x86_64 2018-08-14 https://www.imagemagick.org
```

test.pdf

```
 Properties:
    date:create: 2018-08-18T09:59:37-07:00
    date:modify: 2018-08-18T09:59:37-07:00
    icc:copyright: Copyright Artifex Software 2011
    icc:description: Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile
    pdf:HiResBoundingBox: 60x60+0+0
    pdf:Version: PDF-1.3  1 0 obj << 
    signature: b3783659c15300ffb14e4da501db28afcc0e0b0060286effa74823327a24abd6
  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 2576 bytes
  Artifacts:
    filename: test.pdf
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 8415B
  Number pixels: 3600
  Pixels per second: 360000B
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.009
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-10 Q16 x86_64 2018-08-14 https://www.imagemagick.org
```

Try adding an sRGB.icc profile to your test.jpg file before converting to PDF. See if that helps.

Comment: No, embedding the ICC profile into the JPEG (for example by using `convert` to turn the PDF into a JPEG) does not fix the problem. It only changes which pixel are now different.

Comment: It could be different sRGB.icc profiles. How are you viewing the differences -- what viewer? If I read your note above, Imagemagick compare shows no difference. So the pixel data must be the same. Only meta data differs and that is typically profiles. What version of Imagemagick and platform are you using? What happens when using the profile `convert test.jpg -profile sRGB.icc test.pdf` if you extract the jpg from the pdf using something like pdfimages?

Comment: I have flickered the two jpg and the pdf without adding the profile using Mac Preview and Imagemagick 6.9.10.10 using animate and I do not see any visual difference.

Comment: I think you are reading my question wrongly in several parts. I am not "viewing" the differences as they are tiny (see "Lets visualize the differences"). I am not converting JPEG to PDF using imagemagick because that would certainly change the information because imagemagick re-encodes the JPEG image. To summarize my question: I embed a JPEG into a PDF container (it's bit by bit identical) but the two are rendered differently (as evident by comparing them with imagemagick).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Since you are not using Imagemagick and the issue is not viewing, I have nothing further to suggest. Apologies.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for taking your time to write up a reply to my question! :)

Comment: Could it be your img2pdf tool? Have you tried other tools?

Comment: It could be. But it wasn't. See the accepted answer and my comment to it.

Comment: After a bit more research it turns out, that the different decoder options were indeed the culprit. If I compare with `compare -define jpeg:dct-method=islow` then the images compare as equal. So imagemagick seems to choose a different dct-method than the three PDF rendering engines and that was the cause of the differences I saw.